# Sum values of 2 custom fields in WordPress meta_query for Front-End filter

Tags: wordpress

On a product registration page with a custom post that I created with the help of the Custom Fields plugin, I have a repeater field with a name called discount and the sub fields percent_discount and percent_cashback. On the front end, I add these 2 values together to show the total percentage of benefits it has.

But now the need has arisen for a filter based on the total discount it has, where up front I inform the minimum amount and the maximum amount of total discount it has per product.

I know that in SQL the type SELECT SUM(col1 + col2) AS total_discount FROM myTable.

So I would show all the records where the result of the total_discount field would be between the minimum and maximum value sent in the search.

Now how to do this in a meta query? I don't know if it's possible, but I tried the solution below without success.

```
<?php
$meta_qry = array(
         'relation' => 'AND',
         'pdc' => array(
             'key' => 'percent_discount + percent_cashback',
             'value' => $my_float_value,
             'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
             'type' => 'DECIMAL(10,3)'
         ),
),

$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'products_business',
    'meta_query' => $meta_qry
);

global $query_products_business;
$query_products_business = new WP_Query( $args );
```